# @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@npmreplace with @react-native-community/async-storage

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to implement pinlock screen in my react native application, and i'm like having a dependencies conflict with async storage community package and react native async storage. Is there anyway to replace the async storage community which is deprecated with the new one in a third party library ?

Comment: npm uninstall @react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: the third depedency is using this package not me , i didn't install it, i'm looking to replace the package in the third party library

Comment: if uninstall is not working for you, then try deleting the node_module folder and npm cache as well. then run npm i

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the library repo and replace the deprecated lib with the existing one.

Comment: i did that but when running npm it's installing the old version from the official repo

Comment: You mean that you have changed the lib from package.json and it still install the wrong one?